# Heroku Toolbelt Certs Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to install a certificate from Godaddy in my Heroku. I could do all the steps presented in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint and http://www.joshwright.com/tips/setup-a-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-heroku .

But, right now, I can not use the command "heroku certs" in order to upload my certificate to Heroku. Like this:

```
heroku certs:add combined.crt server.key
```

I am using Heroku Toolbelt on Windows 10. And when I type "heroku certs" the prompt just stops (no message of error or success).

I already have installed the `SSL:ENDPOINT` at my app, so I really do not understand why it is not running.

Can anyone help me?